# Empty Plots - matplotlib only shows frame of plot but no data

Tags: matplotlib

From my excel imported file, I want to plot specific entries i.e.rows and columns but plt.plot command does not display the data, only a blank frame is shown. please see the attached picture. 
May be it has something to do with my code.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
hpge = pd.read_excel('mypath\\filename.xlsx','Sheet3', skiprows=1,usecols='C:G,I,J') 

x=[]
y=[]
x.append(hpge.E_KeV[2700:2900])# E_KeV is a column
y.append(hpge.Fcounts[2700:2900])# Fcounts is a column
x1=[]
y1=[]
x1.append(hpge.E[2700:2900])
y1.append(hpge.C[2700:2900])
#print(y1)
#print(x)
#plt.xlim(590,710)
#plt.yscale('log')
plt.plot(x, y, label='Cs')
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure that `x`, `y`, `x1`, and `y1` are properly filled with the data you want? Did you check their shapes? The code looks fine so it might be a data issue.

Comment: @Francisca yes i printed them,it looks apparently that data is filled in them correctly.